# Python Pandas merge on keywords / sentence

Tags: python, pandas, match, vlookup

I am quite new to python, and I cannot figure out how to solve the problem below:

I have two dataframes, and I want to use some kind of VLOOKUP function that will match a sentence with a particular keyword. In the example below, (df1) the 3e sentence should match with banana (df2) because it contains banana in the sentence.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Text': ['Some text 1', 'Some text 2','The monkey eats a banana','Some text 4']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Keyword': ['apple', 'banana', 'chicken'], 'Type': ['fruit', 'fruit', 'meat']})

df1

    Text
0   Some text 1
1   Some text 2
2   The monkey eats a banana
3   Some text 4

df2

    Keyword Type
0   apple   fruit
1   banana  fruit
2   chicken meat
```

Thus, the preferable outcome would be:

```
    Text                        Type
0   Some text 1                 -
1   Some text 2                 -
2   The monkey eats a banana    fruit
3   Some text 4                 -
```

I already tried to use the merge and str.contains function, the problem, however, is that banana is in a sentence not a standalone value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `extract` for the keywords, and `map` to map extracted "Keyword" to "Type".

```
import re

p = rf"({'|'.join(map(re.escape, df2['Keyword']))})"
# p = '(' + '|'.join(map(re.escape, df2['Keyword'])) + ')'

df1['Type'] = (
    df1['Text'].str.extract(p, expand=False).map(df2.set_index('Keyword')['Type']))
df1

                       Text   Type
0               Some text 1    NaN
1               Some text 2    NaN
2  The monkey eats a banana  fruit
3               Some text 4    NaN
```

Where,

```
p
# '(apple|banana|chicken)'
```